# Splunk rex command with curly brackets, round brackets, period and quotation marks

Tags: command, splunk, rex

I'm having issues with the rex command on splunk. 
My Query outputs the below.

> {"(001) NULL.COUNT(1).NUMBER": "12345"}

I am looking to extract just the value 12345, but at the moment, I have below `rex` command which returns "`{"(001) NULL.COUNT(1).NUMBER": "12345"}`".

```
| rex field=_transfers "(001) NULL.COUNT(1).NUMBER": "(?<value>.*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotation marks have to escaped in the `rex` command.  Also, parentheses in regex strings must be escaped if they're not part of a capture group.  Try `| rex field=_transfers "\\(001) NULL.COUNT\\(1).NUMBER\\": \\"(?<value>.*)"`.